# Identify rows where the time difference between two columns exceed 4 hours

Tags: sql, date, time, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two columns in my table called GXHEAD. there are PRECISETIME and DEVALERT.

Both PRECISETIME and DEVALERT hold time as varchar(255) and are in the format "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS"  (e.g: "20/03/2014 14:07:11").

I would like to identify all rows where DEVALERT exceed PRECISETIME by 4 hours.

Comment: Do *not* store `DATETIME` values as `VARCHAR`...

Comment: With hindsight I would not have done so but it has gone live and the repercussions of me refactoring this are not small.

Comment: Just convert (or cast) the columns as `DATETIME` and then perform `DATEDIFF` on them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DATEDIFF(Hour, Cast(PRECISETIME as DATETIME), Cast(DEVALERTas DATETIME)) > 4
```

Also note that it is a bad practice to store dates as varchar(). You should always avoid that.

Try to set this:

```
set dateformat dmy
```

Comment: I get the following:Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: @TobyDerrum:- Looks like you need to reverse the column: `DATEDIFF(Hour, Cast(DEVALERT as DATETIME), Cast(PRECISETIME  as DATETIME)) > 4`

Comment: @TobyDerrum:- Also try to set the datetime format like this: `set dateformat dmy` at the top of your query.

Comment: I get the following: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @TobyDerrum:- Can you add some sample dates from your database?

Comment: I believe I have some NULL values in DEVALERT, this is most likely causing the issue

Comment: @TobyDerrum:- Try this then: `DATEDIFF(Hour, Cast(ISNULL(PRECISETIME, getdate()) as DATETIME), Cast(ISNULL(DEVALERT,getdate()) DATETIME)) > 4`

Comment: @TobyDerrum:- I have replaced NULL dates to present date. You can change it to whatever date you feel like :) Hope that helps

Comment: I get : "An expression of non boolean type specified, in a context where a condition is expected". Also I may need to mitigate against a "0" value

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know if there is any way I could order my results by either DEVALERT or PRESCISETIME ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to `CONVERT` your columns into a `DATETIME` value and do a `DATEDIFF()` on them.

You should really store your values as their appropriate datatypes, as this is not SARGable at all.

```
Select  *
From    GXHEAD
Where   DateDiff(Hour, Convert(DateTime, PRECISETIME, 103), Convert(DateTime, DEVALERT, 103)) >= 4
```

Comment: I get the following: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: @TobyDerrum Updated to use `CONVERT` with the 103 format for UK-formatted dates.

Comment: It runs for a few lines then conks out with the following message: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @TobyDerrum Have a look at your data - it sounds like there is something else in that column that isn't in the `DATETIME` format.

Comment: You are right, I found some some NULL values in DEVALERT, this is most likely causing the issue.

Comment: Can I mitigate against NULL values  in the SQL query ?

Comment: @TobyDerrum `NULL` values won't throw that error - it would simply make the result `NULL`.  That error is pointing at some data not being in the `DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss` format (e.g.: if one of the values was `apple`, and it can't figure out how to make that a `DATETIME`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93697/discussion-between-toby-derrum-and-siyual).